# Cannot installs Gnome in 12.10

Tags: gnome, 12.10, dependencies

when I try to install gnome DE, i get dependency issues.

the command  `apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-default-settings`

gives the error message -

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-default-settings
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what do I do?

### EDIT

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.6.1-0ubuntu1) but 3.7.1+git20121024.a4e29e12-0ubuntu1~12.10~ricotz0 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only dependency issue is gnome-shell, which is the primary interface for gnome3.  Just install gnome-shell.

Comment: see the edit....another error

Comment: You are using ppa:ricotz/testing and trying to install software from ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3.  `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing`, then add the gnome3 repository.

Comment: i do not have the ricotz ppa installed! i added the gnome 3 ppa but still same error...n i dont have the ricotz ppa added at all

Comment: You still have at least one package from the ricotz ppa.  It's possible that you did not remove it correctly or that you have a package from another ppa that depends on it.  Unfortunately, this can take a very long time to debug.  Try downloading the ricotz ppa and running ppa-purge.

Comment: @astex...yeah i had the "Gnome Tweak Tool" installed which i think was using that ppa...though the ppa was not visible anywhere!